# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning for unclear reason

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
foo = pd.read_csv("foo2.csv", skipinitialspace=True, index_col='Index')
foo.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(foo.Date)

for i in range(0, len(foo)-1):
    if foo.at[i, 'Type'] == 'Reservation':
        for j in range(i+1, len(foo)):
            if foo.at[j, 'Type'] == 'Payout':
                foo.at[j, 'Nights'] = foo.at[i, 'Nights']
                break

mask = (foo['Date'] >= '2018-03-31') & (foo['Date'] <= '2019-03-31')
foo2019 = foo.loc[mask]
foopayouts2019 = foo2019.loc[foo2019['Type'] == 'Payout']
foopayouts2019.loc[:, 'Nights'] = foopayouts2019['Nights'].apply(np.int64)
# foopayouts2019.loc[:, 'Nights'] = foopayouts2019['Nights'].astype(np.int64, copy=False)
```

with `foo2.csv` as:

```
Index,Date,Type,Nights,Amount,Payout
0,03/07/2018,Reservation,2.0,1000.00,
1,03/07/2018,Payout,,,1000.00
2,09/11/2018,Reservation,3.0,1500.00,
3,09/11/2018,Payout,,,1500.00
4,02/16/2019,Reservation,2.0,2000.00,
5,02/16/2019,Payout,,,2000.00
6,04/25/2019,Reservation,7.0,1200.00,
7,04/25/2019,Payout,,,1200.00
```

This gives the following warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

The warning does not mention a line number, but appears to be coming from the line:

```
foopayouts2019.loc[:, 'Nights'] = foopayouts2019['Nights'].apply(np.int64)
```

At least, if I comment that line out, the error goes away. So, I have two questions.

1. What is causing that error? I've been trying to use `.loc` where
   appropriate, including in that line where the warning is (possibly)
   coming from. If the problem is actually earlier, where is it?
2. Second, which is the better choice, `.apply` or `astype`, as used in
   the following lines of code?

   ```
   foopayouts2019.loc[:, 'Nights'] = foopayouts2019['Nights'].apply(np.int64)
   # foopayouts2019.loc[:, 'Nights'] = foopayouts2019['Nights'].astype(np.int64, copy=False)
   ```

   It seems that both of them work, except for that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change a few things in the code:

We are checking if the current row is `Reservation` and the next row is `Payout`
by using [`shift()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+shift&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+shift&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1520j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
and `ffill`-ing the values where condition matches by using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
foo.Date=pd.to_datetime(foo.Date) #convert to datetime
c=foo.Type.eq('Reservation')&foo.Type.shift(-1).eq('Payout')
foo.Nights=np.where(~c,foo.Nights.ffill(),foo.Nights) #replace if else with np.where
```

Or:

```
c=foo.Type.shift().eq('Reservation')&foo.Type.eq('Payout')
np.where(c,foo.Nights.ffill(),foo.Nights)
```

---

Then use [`series.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) to check if dates fall between 2 dates:

```
foo2019 = foo[foo.Date.between('2018-03-31','2019-03-31')].copy() #changes
foopayouts2019 = foo2019[foo2019['Type'] == 'Payout'].copy() #changes .copy()
```

Or directly:

```
foopayouts2019=foo[foo.Date.between('2018-03-31','2019-03-31')&foo.Type.eq('Payout')].copy()
```

---

```
foopayouts2019.loc[:, 'Nights'] = foopayouts2019['Nights'].apply(np.int64) #.astype(int)
```

---

```
   Index       Date    Type  Nights  Amount  Payout
3      3 2018-09-11  Payout       3     NaN  1500.0
5      5 2019-02-16  Payout       2     NaN  2000.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do the `foo2019` and `foopayouts2019` assignments not actually create copies then? And is that what is causing the error message that I'm seeing? Also, in the case of my second question, which is preferable, `.apply` or `.astype`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha no, its creating a slice so any operation/mutation on them will give you that warning. read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas). Also , you can use `np.where()` or `np.select()` for implementing [conditional replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the help. I'm still a bit unclear on the `c` condition and it's usage. Specifically, what does the usage of `-c` in `np.where(~c,...` mean here? I think your answer would benefit generally from some explanation. And not just in side comments. :-)

Comment: @FaheemMitha Updated the answer with explanations, side note `~` is used to inverse a `True` to `False` and vice versa. I added another condition where you dont need the `~` . Hope it helps